# Missing nvidia-settings application

Tags: installation, nvidia, multiple-monitors, screen, settings

To make a long story short, I seem to have lost my nvidia-settings application.  So, when I select Settings from the drop down, and then Display, I don't see the configuration screen that I normally associate with nvidia-settings application. I tried to reinstall, and it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ sudo nvidia-settings
sudo: nvidia-settings: command not found

$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-settings is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.

$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Anyways, what am I over looking?  Also, is there any other nvidia applications I might be missing?

thanks!

**Edit:** As per suggestion I tried to install `nvidia-settings`, but still not working

```
 $ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current 
 Reading package lists... Done 
 Building dependency tree 
 Reading state information... Done 
 nvidia-current is already the newest version. 
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded. 

 $ nvidia-settings 
 nvidia-settings: command not found 

 $ sudo nvidia-settings 
 sudo: nvidia-settings: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install both the driver *and* the corresponding `nvidia-settings` application, which is packaged seperately.

The following will install the latest Nvidia driver with the corresponding `nvidia-settings` application.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates nvidia-settings-updates
```

BTW: You don't always have to run the application as root, only when you want to write the xorg.conf.

Comment: That didn't seem to work.  Here's what I get:  (By the way, someone edited my original post to put my modified screen output in a nice box... how do I do that?)

> $ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> nvidia-current is already the newest version.
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
> 
> $ nvidia-settings
> nvidia-settings: command not found
> 
> $ sudo nvidia-settings
> sudo: nvidia-settings: command not found

Comment: You can paste the content ,select it and press `ctrl + k` or click on <code> button in the toolbar. This is not applicable for comment. Or add 4 spaces before each line

Comment: what is output of `whereis nvidia-settings`

Comment: $ whereis nvidia-settings
nvidia-settings: /usr/bin/nvidia-settings /usr/lib/nvidia-settings /usr/bin/X11/nvidia-settings /usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-settings.1.gz
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games


I see it's not in my path, but I also realize the path I just typed is mine and not root.  How do I get it to show up in root so that when I select the Settings drop down from my desktop window, I can use the program once again?  Thanks!

Comment: Wrong, `nvidia-settings` is recommended by the drivers but is packaged separately and because auf that will not be automatically installed. http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/nvidia-settings http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/nvidia-current

Comment: Well, I've gotten further.  By putting both nvidia packages in the same apt-get install command (as you list above) I was able to run nvidia-settings from the prompt.  But, if I click the 'gear icon' (the thing on the top right corner of my desktop), and if I select Displays..., it doesn't use the nvidia application.  Do I need to do a restart?  anyways, I don't remember now if selecting Displays... is suppose to use the nvidia application.

Anyways, thanks for getting me this far!