# Nvidia-settings is installed according to apt-get, but is missing

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia

Under Kubuntu 14.04, I got trouble with nvidia-settings: whereas it appears as already installed in apt-get, it is nowhere on the computer (or it is well hidden...). I tried to remove and reinstalled, and everything that is suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178593/missing-nvidia-settings-application) aged 2 years, but with no success.

Is this a problem of apt-get (I also tried the graphical driver manager)? Or of nvidia (I tried version 331.113 and 304.125 of the driver)? What can I do?

Some output:

```
$ lspci -k |egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2                                                                                    9:08
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108GLM [NVS 5200M] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0535
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Many thanks!

**EDIT:**
it appears that my nvidi-settings has been "diverted". But I fail to remove it as suggested:

```
$ dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-settings
diversion of /usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/nvidia-settings.png to /var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/nvidia-settings.png by stil-nvidia-run-dkms-340.76
diversion of /usr/share/applications/nvidia-settings.desktop to /var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/share/applications/nvidia-settings.desktop by stil-nvidia-run-dkms-340.76
diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-settings.1.gz to /var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-settings.1.gz by stil-nvidia-run-dkms-340.76
diversion of /usr/bin/nvidia-settings to /var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/bin/nvidia-settings by stil-nvidia-run-dkms-340.76
```

But the following does not work:

```
$ sudo dpkg-divert --rename --remove /var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/bin/nvidia-settings
No diversion 'any diversion of /var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/bin/nvidia-settings', none removed.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `/usr/bin/nvidia-settings` terminal command.

Comment: I don't have `/usr/bin/nvidia-settings`...

Comment: Please [edit] your question an add output of `lspci -k |egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2`

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-settings

Comment: Does not work... nvidia-settings is still located at `/var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/bin/nvidia-settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a permissions problem with nvidia-settings.

Run the following command on your system in a terminal window to see what permissions that `nvidia-settings` might have:

`find / -type f -name nvidia-settings -printf '%M %p\n' 2>/dev/null`

It should have the following permissions set for it:

`-rwxr-xr-x /usr/bin/nvidia-settings`

If it does not look like above, type in the following to correct it to make it so it can be run:

`sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/nvidia-settings`

Also, it should have root at both the user and group for it.  Type in the following to show permissions, user, and group info:

`ls -l /usr/bin/nvidia-settings`

the output should look like:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 208160 May 21 03:23 /usr/bin/nvidia-settings`

if you don't see `root root` then type in the following to correct it:

`sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/nvidia-settings`

**EDIT:**

Well, we have certainly found out something here.  Somehow your package of `nvidia-settings` has been diverted.   Go to the bottom of the manpage about diversion [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/dpkg-divert.8.html) and see if you can't remove the diversion then reinstall `nvidia-settings`.  If push comes to shove, you could always create a link to `nvidia-settings` so it will launch.

Or check here for diverted package removal and reinstall [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Adding%20and%20removing%20diversions).

You might also be able to find the diversion first by typing in the following:

`dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-settings`

then when you find it, type in the following to remove the diversion:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --rename --remove --divert "/var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/bin/nvidia-settings" /usr/bin/nvidia-settings
```

You can try replacing the diversion names in the command above for all diversions that were found during the `dpkg-divert -list` by replacing the entries that you listed here:

```
$ dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-settings
diversion of /usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/nvidia-settings.png to /var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/nvidia-settings.png by stil-nvidia-run-dkms-340.76
diversion of /usr/share/applications/nvidia-settings.desktop to /var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/share/applications/nvidia-settings.desktop by stil-nvidia-run-dkms-340.76
diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-settings.1.gz to /var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-settings.1.gz by stil-nvidia-run-dkms-340.76
diversion of /usr/bin/nvidia-settings to /var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/bin/nvidia-settings by stil-nvidia-run-dkms-340.76
```

So, how the command would work for each one listed here, is that the first link listed after `diversion of` is the original name.  And after the `to` part of that line is the diverted package name, so another example would be:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --rename --remove --divert "/var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/nvidia-settings.png" /usr/share/doc/NVIDIA_GLX-1.0/nvidia-settings.png
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have `/usr/bin/nvidia-settings`. The ouput of `find / -type f -name nvidia-settings -printf '%M %p\n' 2>/dev/null` is `-rwxr-xr-x /var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/bin/nvidia-settings`. What is this??

Comment: I add that nvidia-settings in `/var/lib/stil/diverted-files/usr/bin/nvidia-settings` seems to work. But why is it there? And what does it mean to be there?

Comment: @janou195  Well, we have certainly found out something here.  Somehow your package of `nvidia-settings` has been diverted.   Go to the bottom of the manpage about diversion below and see if you can't remove the diversion then reinstall `nvidia-settings`.  If push comes to shove, you could always create a link to `nvidia-settings` so it will launch.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/dpkg-divert.8.html

Comment: @janou195 I also added an edit to my answer to another location about removing a package diversion.

Comment: The `sudo dpkg-divert --rename --remove ...` does not seem to work. I added the output in the question. Thanks

Comment: @janou195 I have made one more change to try.  I am honestly trying to figure this out as well, and I thank you for your patience with me!

Comment: @janou195 You're very welcome!  :)